# Multiprocessing Z3 in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle, z3, z3py

I have a large list of various types of objects I would like Z3 to synthesize in my Python project. Since constraints associated with each object to be synthesized are independent, this process can be completely parallelized. That is, instead of synthesizing one value at a time, if I have a machine with 4 cores, I can synthesize 4 values at the same time. To do this, we must use Python's `multiprocessing` package instead of `threading` (due to GIL and the fact that the workload should be CPU-bound).

For simplicity, say I have a simple `str` synthesizer that synthesizes a new `str` that is lexicographically less than a given input `value`, something like this:

```
def lt_constraint(value):
    solver = Solver()
    # do a number of processing on 'value', which is an input string
    # ... define char and _chars in code here
    template = Concat(Re(StringVal(value[:offset])), char, Star(_chars))
    solver.add(InRe(String("var"), template))
    if solver.check() == sat:
        value = solver.model()[self.var]
        return convert_to_str(value)
```

Now if I have a number of `value`s, I want to run the function above in parallel:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    value_list = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
    synthesized_strs = pool.map(lt_constraint, value_list)
```

I use `pathos` hoping that it will handle pickling issue, but I still received this error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 're.Match' object
```

which I believe is because Z3 uses methods in `re` and they need to be pickled when pickling `lt_constraint()`, but `dill` cannot pickle those.

Is there any other way to parallelize Z3 for my case (other than implementing pickling myself for `re` or what not)?

Thanks!

Comment: If your framework depends on pickling/serialization, you'll have to implement that yourself. Solver.to_string gives you a textual representation of the constraints in the solver, but loading these into another solver may not necessarily be painless. A common usage pattern for parallel settings is to simply use on Z3 context per thread/core and all the constraints are created for each context (there are also translation functions that translate between contexts).

Answer (score 0):

Stack-overflow works the best when you include your whole code, so people can experiment with it. Having said that, I had good luck with the following:

```py
from z3 import *
import concurrent.futures

def getVal(value):
    solver = Solver()
    var = Int('var')
    solver.add(var > value)
    if solver.check() == sat:
        return solver.model()[var].as_long()
    else:
        return 'CANT SOLVE'

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(getVal, i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
    results = [f.result() for f in futures]
    print(results)
```

This prints:

```
$ python3.9 a.py
[2, 3, 4]
```

Without actually having the details of how you constructed your `lt_constraint`, it's hard to tell whether this'll work for your case. But it seems using the `concurrent.futures` library works well with z3; so far as simple constraints are used. Give this a try and see if it handles your case as well. If not; please post the full-code as an minimal-reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example